# Remove specified packages if they have no dependencies

Tags: package-management, apt, dpkg

I installed a package by mistake and immediately removed (purged it to be exact) it, but other than the package itself, none of the dependencies that installed alongside was removed. I do not know if it's required or not, but if no, I would like to remove them.

Comment: Can you indicate which package you installed?

Comment: `ubuntu-applet-session` on minimal install.

Comment: There is no such package, do you mean `indicator-applet-session`? Anyway I would have an answer if it was a metapackage, but it is not.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how I misplaced `indicator` with `ubuntu`, but yes that's the package in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[man apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-get.8.html) provides information that the parameter `autoremove` is used to remove packages that were automatically downloaded to satisfy dependencies for some package and are no longer required.

So, you could use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove dependencies that are now useless.

Additional source: [Ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-clean-up-your-packages.html)

Comment: I know about that, but usually it says at the end of an `apt-get` install/remove process that there are some packages that needs to be removed. But after installing the package in question I only removed it, and no mentioned of orphaned packages.

Comment: This is the tricky bit, the packages came a dependency of package x (I'm naming it for convenience), but they did not become orphaned after package x was removed.

Comment: so it's very probable that they are being used by a different application.

Comment: But how? Like I said, I removed package x immediately, I did not install any other packages that may have those dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If apt-get's autoremove doesn't help, you can run this (needs `aptitude`, takes **very** long, like an hour! - no idea if this can be done faster):

```
for i in $(dpkg -l  | grep "^ii" | awk '{print $2}'); do aptitude why "$i"; done | grep "Unable to find"
```

This will list *all* packages which aptitude can find no reason why they are installed (but you maybe installed them manually).

Comment: Gah, I need to do that for a few packages...?

Comment: You *can* - or wait for a better answer. ;)

Comment: Any `apt-get` equivalent?

Comment: I don't know anything else than autoremove. Can't you take a look at your dpkg history in Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic?

Comment: Minimal install. Oh right, maybe I should consider installing either of them but currently it's only a command line.

Comment: cat /var/log/dpkg.log ;)